# Capture PersonID from INSERT statement and use it to redirect to details page

Tags: redirect

I want to get the PersonID from the INSERT statement and use it to redirect the user to the details page of the last inserted record. The column PersonID is set to auto increment.

I am using this script:

```
echo("<script>location.href = 'details_person.php?PersonID=$PersonID';</script>");
```

The details page opens but without the PersonID in the url:

```
details_person.php?PersonID=
```

How do I capture that PersonID after insert?

I also have tried to get the ID as follows but still I have a blank id in the url:

```
`$PersonID = mysql_insert_id();`
```

Comment: I think I figured it out.